# In vb.net, datagridview does not display value in cell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am using vb.net. I have following weird problems: 
If I comment DGVCusClient.Rows.Add(), the cell in ("column1",0) does not display data. But in debug, I can see that the first cell has data assigned.
If I do not comment DGVCusClient.Rows.Add(), the cell in ("column1",0) displays its data correctly. However, it adds the row on the top for the first time. Except for the first row, it adds rows to the bottom as usual.

```
                Dim i As Integer = DGVCusClient.CurrentRow.Index
    If Not ContainRecord(tempCusid, tempCltid) Then
        Dim i As Integer = DGVCusClient.CurrentRow.Index

        DGVCusClient.Item("Column1", i).Value = "a"
        DGVCusClient.Item("Column2", i).Value = "b"
                         'DGVCusClient.Rows.Add()

    End If

Private Function ContainRecord(ByVal strCusid As String, ByVal strCltid As String) As Boolean
    For i As Integer = 0 To DGVCusClient.Rows.Count - 1
        If Not DGVCusClient.Item("Column1", i).Value Is Nothing AndAlso Not DGVCusClient.Item("Column2", i).Value Is Nothing Then
            If DGVCusClient.Item("Column1", i).Value.ToString = strCusid AndAlso DGVCusClient.Item("Column2", i).Value.ToString = strCltid Then
                Return True
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: Why do you have duplicated "i" variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code can always add rows to the bottom, which is what I want. So I just need to first add new row, and then set values to current cells.

```
If Not ContainRecord("a", "b") Then
Dim i As Integer = DGVCusClient.CurrentRow.Index
DGVCusClient.Rows.Add()
DGVCusClient.Item("Column1", i).Value = "a"   
DGVCusClient.Item("Column2", i).Value = "b" 
End If
```